# MySQL server connection issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

Someone tell me please why the given below error is occurring again and again even i wrote the correct host name.

ERROR: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1130, "Host 'Hostname' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")

Note: I this question I wrote the 'Hostname' but in my project i wrote the required name.

I check my host name using cmd and also using mysql workbench they display the same server name.I stop the server in services and again start it bt again same issue occurs, also wrote that host name in project but the above error occurs again and again

Comment: It's the "not allowed" part that's key here, it means the server is configured to reject your connection.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could do.

Go to the MySQL admin and check user permissions, using this command:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'Hostname';
```

Ensure that there is a grant that allows connections from this host. If not, use this command:

```
GRANT ALL ON database.* TO 'username'@'Hostname';
```

ps.: replace the variables with your own:

database - your database name

username - MySQL username your Django application is using

Hostname - hostname or IP address your Django application is using

If it is not the problem, check the firewall. You must allow traffic on the MySQL port (default is 3306).

If none of this works, double check your hostname, your Django database and application's settings.